# gcloud Logging Sink does not have a way to specify to create partitioned table?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-logging

I am creating a gcloud logging sink using the following command

```
gcloud logging sinks create $MONITORING_SINK bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/$PROJECTID/datasets/$PROJECT_MONITORING_DATASET_NAME --log-filter "resource.type=bigquery_resource jobservice.jobcompleted"
```

If I were to do it through the GUI, there is an optional checkbox to select if the table created as an output of this sink would be partitioned or not. But there is no way to do this using the gcloud statement as far as I can tell?

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Google's official documentation, yes, there is a way to create it partitioned, you just need to use --use-partitioned-tables, please check further info under [1].

Have a great day!

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/logging/sinks/create

Comment: Aah! So it's there for the alpha but not in the non alpha/beta one https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/sinks/create. Does this mean I have to use alpha at this point?

Comment: Also, when creating the sink, it does not create the cloudaudit_googleapis_com_data_access table until I go to that sink and click "Start Streaming". Is this a bug or is there a way I can invoke this?